# Hibernate issue

Tags: hibernate

I'm using Hibernate with Struts.

I want to copy data of one table to another table, so I had done something like this:

```
public boolean updateAllScrutinyTables() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        String query = "";

        try{
            query = "insert into SRequisitionAge select * from RequisitionAge ra where ra.Requisition.id = 7";


            session.beginTransaction();
            session.createQuery(query).executeUpdate();
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            return true;
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.error("Error in SRequisitionPostDAOImpl.updateAllScrutinyTables() : "+e.toString());
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and when I will execute this I will get this error

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting OPEN, found 'select' near line 1, column 29 [insert into SRequisitionAge select * from com.sttl.rpsc.dataobject.RequisitionAge ra where ra.Requisition.id = 7]
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:281)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1650)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor256.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:342)
    at $Proxy7.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at com.sttl.rpsc.dao.SRequisitionPostDAOImpl.updateAllScrutinyTables(SRequisitionPostDAOImpl.java:135)
    at com.sttl.rpsc.service.RequisitionServiceImpl.updateAllScrutinizeReqTables(RequisitionServiceImpl.java:268)
    at com.sttl.rpsc.action.RequisitionAction.setScrutinizePostRequisition(RequisitionAction.java:1894)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:441)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:280)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:243)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:89)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:488)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:395)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

What's the problem? Can I do something like this in hibernate? If not, then what's the alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you don't need to invovle much of hibernate, so you can do it with a native query - `createSQLQuery(..)`

Apart from that, you can:

- select all entities
- iterate them, and on each iteration create a new object from the new type and set the corresponding fields
- save the new entity.

It will require much more queries though

Comment: hi bozho, thanks for reply, but i had no permission to use NativeQuery in my system so i have to use create query so is there is  any alternative or i have to correct anything at here only??

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing your query like this:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("insert into Stock(stock_code, stock_name)" +
                "select stock_code, stock_name from backup_stock");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: hi nikunj, thanks for reply, i had tried this (http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-query-examples-hql/) , nu ti have some reference in my table so i have to make query with  fieldname or that POJO name in query??

Comment: Should be POJO properties for HQL.

Comment: The pseudo-syntax for INSERT statements is: INSERT INTO EntityName properties_list select_statement.
Only the INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... form is supported; not the INSERT INTO ... VALUES ... form.
The properties_list is analogous to the column specification in the SQL INSERT statement. For entities involved in mapped inheritance, only properties directly defined on that given class-level can be used in the properties_list. Superclass properties are not allowed and subclass properties do not make sense. In other words, INSERT statements are inherently non-polymorphic.